# Lock screen shortcuts Android Lollipop

Tags: applications, lock-screens

I used to swipe to text and so on, without any external apps. Now, with this new "update" I can only access phone (swipe to the right) or camera (swipe to the left). Can one change these?

BTW I'm on a Nexus 4 google LG phone.

Comment: I don't remember you can have custom shortcut on lockscreen on Nexus 4 on previous Android versions either... or, did you mean the lockscreen widget?

Comment: Yes lock screen widget.

Comment: I used the SMS shortcut all the time but now there's a phone there instead (who casks people anyway? )

Comment: I'm afraid I have to say that [Google has done away with the lockscreen widgets](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2851690/how-to-make-the-most-of-android-5-0-lollipop-s-new-lock-screen-settings.html). As of current, I haven't found and done further research the alternative.

Comment: Yep it seems like that. Oh well.